# Getting text out of file object Python

Tags: python

I am a student trying to learn Python and I'm stumped on turning a file object it text.  Here's my code:

```
def file2table(filename, mycaption=None):

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return lists2table(file, mycaption)

def lists2table(mylists, mycaption=None):

    result = '<table>\n'
    if mycaption != None:
        result += '<caption>' + mycaption + '</caption>\n'
    result += list2THrow(mylists[0]) + '\n'
    for item in mylists[1:]:
        result += list2TDrow(item) + '\n'
    result += '</table>'
    return result
```

Error is:

```
result = '<table>\n<caption>Table with Forbes Top 50 Women</caption>\n', global list2THrow = <function list2THrow>, mylists = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='data/forbeswomen_ascii.tsv' mode='r' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable 
      args = ("'_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable",) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>
```

Comment: I think you want `return lists2table(file.readlines(), mycaption)`, as `lists2table` seems to be expecting a list, but without much more information it's hard to be certain. The code is quite confusing, and seems to have some typos.

Comment: you can iterate over the file object also, you don't need to read all into memory unless you must.

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  The '.readlines()' did the trick.  Not quite sure how to uproot this.

Answer (score 0):

This line right here:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return lists2table(file, mycaption)
```

`file` in this case is a file object, not the contents. In order to get the text out you need to do `file.read()`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it appears you want to create a table with entries from a file.Now you are passing file object to your function `lists2table` and then you are trying to subscript it as a list that's why you are getting this error.You can try to use any of the following approach

```
def file2table(filename, mycaption=None):

    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return lists2table(file.readlines(), mycaption)
```

readlines() return a list of lines in the file.
Or you can pass the file object in the function

```
def lists2table(mylists, mycaption=None):

    result = '<table>\n'
    mylists = mylists.read().split('\n')#this creates the desired list
    if mycaption != None:
        result += '<caption>' + mycaption + '</caption>\n'
    result += list2THrow(mylists[0]) + '\n'
    for item in mylists[1:]:
        result += list2TDrow(item) + '\n'
    result += '</table>'
    return result
```